# Angular filtering an array but excluding first element from filter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects that I am filtering. I don't want the first element in the array to be removed in the filter.

For example, the array (`oData`) may look like this:

```
[
 {id: "abc1", type: "car"},
 {id: "h445", type: "car"},
 {id: "kjj6", type: "van"},
 {id: "5yee", type: "bus"}
]
```

I'm applying a filter to remove elements where the type is in a list of user selected options as follows:

```
this.dataSet = this.oData.filter((d) => this.sOptions.includes(d.type));
```

If the user has selected 'van' and 'bus', the dataset looks like this:

```
[
 {id: "kjj6", type: "van"},
 {id: "5yee", type: "bus"}
]
```

However, I want the first element `{id: "abc1", type: "car"}` to always remain, i.e I want it to be excluded from the filter.

I have tried filtering and then using unShift() to add it back in but it is behaving strangely.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 2nd argument passed to the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback that represents the index of the current item. You can use to exclude the first element.

```
let data = [
 {id: "abc1", type: "car"},
 {id: "h445", type: "car"},
 {id: "kjj6", type: "van"},
 {id: "5yee", type: "bus"}
];

let selectedOptions = [
    "van",
    "bus"
]

let filtered = data.filter((item, idx) => {
    return idx === 0 || selectedOptions.indexOf(item.type) > -1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
//PRINTS: [{"id":"abc1","type":"car"},{"id":"kjj6","type":"van"},{"id":"5yee","type":"bus"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
arr.filter(num => num !== arr[0] && yourConditionHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, you can do it like this

```
var arr2 = this.oData.filter(a => a.type == "van" || a.type == "bus");
this.dataSet = [this.oData[0], ...arr2];
```